# eclipse - plugins wrongly removed from disk

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt

I was searching to delete the plugins related to org.eclipse.cdt, cause I no longer use C/C++.  The org.eclipse.cdt weren't listed under Installation Details> Installed software, so I decided to directly delete the files from the /plugins folder. Now, Eclipse returns these error logs at startup.

[image]

Main question:

1. How can I fix the problem?

Others:

2. Is it safe to assume that no other plugins uses the deleted ones? (I'm mostly using Android, Genymotion, Tomcat, Apache, JBoss, Hibernate, Spring)
3. What is the right way to delete a plugin (both from eclipse ide and from disk)?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to uninstall a plugin in Eclipse:

1. Go to "Help" menu and select "About Eclipse". Alternatively, if you use MacOS X, you should open the Eclipse menu and select "About Eclipse".
2. Click on the "Installation Details" button.
3. In the "Installed Software" tab, select the plugin you would like to remove and click on the "Uninstall" button.

Now answering your questions.

1. Try to follow above instructions and see if it can uninstall CDT properly.
2. It depends on the plugins you have installed.
3. Check above instructions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The org.eclipse.cdt plugins are not in that list and they aren't there yet before I deleted the files. It is why I decided to delete them directly from the disk. Also, I'm using some other plugins, but mostly Android, Genymotion, Tomcat, Apache, JBoss, Hibernate, Spring.

Comment: improved the OQ in reply to your answer.

Comment: Do you see anything like "C/C++ Development Tools" there?

Comment: nothing, I think I deleted the plugins some weeks ago

Answer (score 0):

As you've learned, it's a bad idea to mess around with Eclipse's `/plugins` directory (or any other internal state); dependency management is a fairly complex task and Eclipse has components specifically designed to do it, so just deleting plugins from the file system will screw things up.

My advice is to install a new copy of Eclipse and point it to your existing workspace. Doing so will restore the IDE without losing your projects or workspace settings. You can even install other plugins that you might have installed before easily, via **File** > **Import...** > **Install** > **From Existing Installation**.

Comment: Well, you're right, but I thought it was safe; on the other hand, they weren't even on the list. So, according to you, there is no way to recover this installation? Just curious: why they aren't automatically deleted from disk?

Comment: I didn't say there is *no way* to recover, just that I think the best/most efficient approach is to start over.

Comment: Eclipse does not necessarily delete plugin JARs or folders when you remove them from Eclipse via its UI because it has a rollback feature - you can revert your Eclipse installation to previous states. So plugins are left on disk to enable that feature.